# Is there anyway i can use expect without installing?

Tags: c, expect

I want to automate expect for `passwd` but I don't have permission to install.
But if I could copy and paste the expect source code and execute the `.c files using`cc/gcc
`and generate the executable expect.`

or

Can I copy the expect executable from linux and just use it anywhere else like on solaris, aix etc?

This is the expect in /usr/bin/expect in my linux box:

```
[root@test]# file /usr/bin/expect
/usr/bin/expect: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prebuilt executables for Solaris and Linux at [kbskit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbskit/files/kbs/0.4.4/) include Expect (along with lots of other Tcl extensions) in the *bi "Batteries Included" versions.  Each is just one big file, no unpacking or installing is needed, apart from eg. `chmod a+x SunOS_kbsvq8.5-bi` to make the file executable.  You use this executable to run your script, and at the start of the script you need to add `package require Expect` to set up the Expect commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C compiler, you can build `expect` (but you have to build `Tcl` first).

The executable from Linux can't be used almost anywhere else (on solaris, aix, etc.); there is a chance for it to work on FreeBSD.

Comment: i have a c compiler, how do i do that? and how can i build tcl or check whether its there or not

Comment: Download tcl sources, unpack them and see further details in `unix/README` file. Then download `expect` sources, unpack them and see further details in `INSTALL` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Solaris 11 then installing **expect** is as easy as:

`pkg install //solaris/shell/expect`

The package will come from the official Oracle Solaris repository so nothing to worry about. There's no need to get sources, build, etc.

I understand that you may not have permission to do this but since this comes from official source (Oracle) I'm pretty sure your sysadmin will do it in a sec.